# PostgreSQL: Column DEFAULT gen_random_bytes UNIQUE

Tags: postgresql, random, unique, default

Let's say we have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    column_1 bigint,
    column_2 bytea DEFAULT gen_random_bytes(2),
    PRIMARY KEY (column_1, column_2)
);
```

Note: We want `column_2` to be random & cryptographically strong.

How do we insert a row without causing a primary key conflict?

I guess we'd have to do a loop until `gen_random_bytes(2)` returns a unique result? If so, can we do this loop with pure `SQL`, maybe with recursive CTE, instead of with `plpgsql`?

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into t (col1, col2)
select 1, ('\x' || right('000' || to_hex(i), 4))::bytea
from (
    select generate_series(0, 65535) i
    except
    select get_byte(col2, 0) * 256 + get_byte(col2, 1)
    from t
    where col1 = 1
) s
order by random()
limit 1
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe the question wasn't clear. We only want to insert one row.

Comment: @mattdipasquale: New answer